# How to create a new joined table record without creating a new instance of either record. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a three tables: `User`, `fruits`, `user_fruits`

There are set number of users and fruits in the world. I cannot create duplicate fruits. Say the fruits already exist in the database, and I want to use them, so I'm not creating new fruits.

Assume we're in a controller and all I want to do is create a new instance of `user_fruits`. I also want to delete the joined table instance in the destroy action but not the actual fruit itself. Is this the way to do it?

```
def create
   user.user_fruits.create!(fruit: fruit)
end

def destroy
   user.user_fruits.find_by(fruit: fruit).destroy!
end


private

attr_reader :fruit

def load_fruit
@fruit = Fruit.find_by(color: red, sweetness: 100)
end
```

I also want my destroy and create to raise an error if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create a new instance then you can simply use `new` or `build`

```
def create
  @new_fruit = user.fruits.new # or fruits.build
end
```

**Update**

New instance of `user_fruits`?
Then you should try something like..

```
user.user_fruits.new

def create
  user.user_fruits.create!(fruit_id: @fruit.id)
end

def destroy
 user.user_fruits.find_by_fruit_id(@fruit.id).destroy!
end
```

And if you want to use reader anyway then replace `@fruit` with `fruit`

Comment: I made an edit to my post. Say the fruits all exist already in the database. The thing I need to create is the joined table row.

Comment: By `fruit` you mean `@fruit`?

Comment: There's an attr_reader for `fruit` so `fruit` refers to `@fruit`

Comment: I don't need it, it's just there for use

Comment: Yeah..that's redundant...and I don't recommend this in controller..as such things belongs to model.